# How to make table responsive?

Tags: html, css, responsive

I've been trying to make this responsive. When I shrink the size of the window or look at it on a phone, I would like it to put the second column in a new row so I have 3 rows and each has 100% of it.

Also, there might be a better way of doing this where you don't use tables so if you could suggest something else I would be grateful.

**PHP**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="hr">
<head>
<?php
$title = "Foto | Album";
$description = "Web aplikacija za besplatno dijelenje fotografija"; 
$keywords = "dijelenje fotografija, komentiranje, kategorije"; 
    include "includes/head.php";
?>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="red">
        <?php include "includes/header.php"; ?>
    </div>


    <div class="red">
    <table  class="t-kolona-12 d-kolona-12">
            <tr>
                <td id="table1"> <?php include "includes/navigation.php"; ?> </td>
                <td rowspan="2"><section id="sadrzaj" class="t-kolona-9 d-kolona-12">
                <!--sadržaj-->
            </section>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td> <?php include "includes/aside.php"; ?></td>
            </tr>
    </table>
    </div>
    <div class="red">
        <?php include "includes/footer.php"; ?>
    </div>
    
</body>
</html>
```

**CSS**

```
body{
    margin: 0;
}

#zaglavlje{
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12), 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.24);
    height: 310px;
    background: url(../images/slike/header_img1.jpg) no-repeat center center/cover;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

#zaglavlje h1{
    color: #ffffff;
    margin: 0;
    font-size: 50px;
    text-shadow: 2px 2px 2px black;

}

#navigacija ul{
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

#navigacija li{
    margin-bottom: 7px;
    background-color: #d8dde2;
    text-align: center;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rga(0, 0, 0, 0.12), 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.24);
}

#navigacija a{
    color: #000000;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    padding: 10px;
}

#navigacija li:hover{
    background-color: #c7cbcf;
}

#sadrzaj{
    box-shadow: 0px 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.12), 0px 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.24);
    margin-bottom:20px;
    min-height:500px;
    max-height:2000px;
    overflow:auto;
}


#prijava form{
    padding: 15px;
    background-color: #d8dde2;
    color: #000000;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rga(0, 0, 0, 0.12), 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.24);
}

#prijava h2{
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0 0 10px 0;
}

#prijava label{
    display: block;
    width: 90%;
    margin: auto;
}

#prijava input[type="text"], #prijava input[type="password"]{
    display: block;
    width: 90%;
    margin: auto;
}

#prijava input[type="submit"]{
    display: block;
    margin: auto;
    color: #000000;
    background-color: #d8dde2;
    font-size: 16px;
}

#podnozje{
    background-color: #bbbfc4;
    color: #000000;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 14px;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rga(0, 0, 0, 0.12), 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.24);
}

#table1{
    width: 300px;
}


/* responzivnost */
img, video, iframe, object{
    max-width: 100%;
}

@media(min-width: 700px){
    #navigacija li{
        text-align: left;
    }
}

@media(min-width: 750px){
    #zaglavlje{
        background: url(../images/slike/header_img_mobile1.jpg) no-repeat center center/cover;
    }
}


/* layout */
*{
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.red:after{
    content: "";
    clear: both;
    display: block;
}

/* mobile */
[class*="kolona"]{
    float: left;
    padding: 10px;
    width: 100%;
}

/* tablet*/
@media (min-width:700px){
.t-kolona-1{width:8.33%;}
.t-kolona-2{width:16.66%;}
.t-kolona-3{width:25%;}
.t-kolona-4{width:33.33%;}
.t-kolona-5{width:41.66%;}
.t-kolona-6{width:50%;}
.t-kolona-7{width:58.33%;}
.t-kolona-8{width:66.66%;}
.t-kolona-9{width:75%;}
.t-kolona-10{width:83.33%;}
.t-kolona-11{width:91.66%;}
.t-kolona-12{width:100%;}
}

/* desktop */
@media (min-width:1100px){
    .d-kolona-1{width:8.33%;}
    .d-kolona-2{width:16.66%;}
    .d-kolona-3{width:25%;}
    .d-kolona-4{width:33.33%;}
    .d-kolona-5{width:41.66%;}
    .d-kolona-6{width:50%;}
    .d-kolona-7{width:58.33%;}
    .d-kolona-8{width:66.66%;}
    .d-kolona-9{width:75%;}
    .d-kolona-10{width:83.33%;}
    .d-kolona-11{width:91.66%;}
    .d-kolona-12{width:100%;}
}
```

Comment: via your querymedia, you can reset td to display:block;they will stand on top of each others. Also watch the code produced .. i see a single td on the second row, but no colspan, a closing section tag all alone where it is not allowed , .. instead table, you can look at display:grid and mediaquerie to reorder the layout ;)

Comment: instead of table you can use grid ... I think grid is so much better when you want to make it responsive